# Selecting newest row by date with interval and groupping by the client ID (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, unique, intervals

I have been trying to select a (the) NEWEST entry for a customer (which will be run by the WP plugin, sorta cron), which I thought would ba 5 mins job. Four hours later I am here, turning to you for help.

To visualize the output and the problem:

```
SELECT * FROM `foc_program_partnerski_historia` 
    WHERE `data` >= SUBDATE('2019-06-30 00:01:00', INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
    AND `zmiana` NOT LIKE '-%' 
ORDER by main_id, `data` DESC
```

[image]

I need to find the newest entry, the highest 'PO' number *, for each client and check if this falls into the interval (the inverval will be later be changed to "equals to", to exactly get the ouput from 10 days ago, 30 days ago or 365 days ago (that will be up to the client).

This is what I would like to see:

[image]

When I add 'group by' clause, it does group it, yes, just not the way I would like it:

[image]

and it takes forver, too...

What should be the proper sql, can you help me out?

.

.

.

.

`

*
Przed /zmiana /po

means:

before /change /after

Comment: PHP is not my strong suit, but why have you even tagged this with php?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you need to GROUP BY main_id.
Start with something like

```
SELECT main_id, max(data) AS data, max(przed) AS przed, min(po) AS po
FROM `foc_program_partnerski_historia` 
    WHERE `data` >= SUBDATE('2019-06-30 00:01:00', INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
    AND `zmiana` NOT LIKE '-%' 
GROUP BY main_id
ORDER BY main_id
```

then you can join to that like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `foc_program_partnerski_historia` A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT main_id, max(data) AS data, max(przed) AS przed, min(po) AS po
  FROM `foc_program_partnerski_historia` 
      WHERE `data` >= SUBDATE('2019-06-30 00:01:00', INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
      AND `zmiana` NOT LIKE '-%' 
  GROUP BY main_id
) B
ON A.main_id = B.main_id AND A.przed=B.po -- OR A.data<>B.data
ORDER BY A.main_id
```

and I'm using max(data) rather than przed based on what you highlighted, although it looks like either will have the results *in this particular case*.

Comment: Thank you, Gary, for your input. My brains might not work as usual, so I have another (dumb) question: after running the first query how exactly can I run "then" (join)? I really thought this would be an easy task...

Comment: The second query is an example. I have made the first query a subquery which is aliased as "B". I am joining A to B, so you have them side by side rather than in sequential rows. You can add any needed calculations from there.